# Dynamic Lambda with all properties of a property of an object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection, linq-to-entities

I had asked a question on how to dynamically compile a LINQ query with all the properties of an object and houlgap had been kind enough to give me the following code

```
    private static Func<MyEntity, bool> GenerateLambda(MyEntity _myEntity, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, "i");
    var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
    var propertyValue = Expression.Constant(propertyInfo.GetValue(_myEntity, null));
    var equalityCheck = Expression.Equal(property, propertyValue);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, bool>>(equalityCheck, instance).Compile();
}
```

This works great if the property to be queried is directly a member of the object but for me there is an intermediate property in between. For e.g. The Func Delegate is for another type e.g. Func`<ABCMyEntity,bool>` while the MyEntity is a member of this object (ABCMyEntity.MyEntity). The Propertyinfo object which is passed is a member of MyEntity.

I know it sounds terribly confusing but I am not able to better explain it. (Maybe because I am not a native speaker). Please ask me if something is not clear in the question.

It is continued from [Constructing Dynamic LINQ queries with all properties of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183092/constructing-dynamic-linq-queries-with-all-properties-of-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a chain of properties (e.g. `v.MyEntity.OtherProperty`) then you can just call `Expression.Property` multiple times:

```
var prop1 = // first property
var prop2 = // second property

// Variable has type of the declarating type of the 1st property
var instance = Expression.Parameter(prop1.DeclaringType, "i"); 

// Get first property on the 'instance'
var expr1 = Expression.Property(instance, prop1); 
// Get second property on the previous expression
var expr2 = Expression.Property(expr, prop2); 

// The rest of the code stays the same (only use 'expr2')
var propertyValue = Expression.Constant(propertyInfo.GetValue(_myEntity, null)); 
var equalityCheck = Expression.Equal(expr2, propertyValue); 
return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, bool>>
  (equalityCheck, instance).Compile();
```

If you need to access more than just two properties, you can easily turn the part that calls `Expression.Property` into a loop - you would just iterate over a list of desired properties and add property access to the expression using `Expression.Property`.